# Apache Spark join/cogroup on generic type RDD

Tags: scala, generics, apache-spark, rdd

I have a problem with the `join` or `cogroup` methods on `RDD`. In detail, I have to join two `RDD`s and one of them is an `RDD` of a generic type, used with wildcard.

```
val indexedMeasures = measures.map(m => (m.id(), m)) // RDD[(String, Measure[_]]
val indexedRegistry = registry.map(r => (r.id, r))   // RDD[(String, Registry)]
indexedRegistry.cogroup(indexedMeasures)
```

The last statement gives a compile time error, which is the following:

```
no type parameters for method cogroup: (other: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, W)])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Iterable[Registry], 
 Iterable[W]))] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Measure[?0]) forSome { type ?0 }]) --- because --- argument expression's type is not compatible 
 with formal parameter type; found : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Measure[?0]) forSome { type ?0 }] required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, ?W)] Note: (String, 
 Measure[?0]) forSome { type ?0 } >: (String, ?W), but class RDD is invariant in type T. You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)
```

What's going on here? Why can't I `cogroup` `RDD`s that use a generic wildcarded type?

Thanks for all of your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is stated in this article [Towards Equal Rights for Higher-kinded Types](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.112.6348&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

> Generics are a very popular feature of contemporary OO languages,
>   such as Java, C# or Scala. Their support for genericity is lacking, however. The
>   problem is that they only support abstracting over proper types, and not over
>   generic types. This limitation makes it impossible to, e.g., define a precise interface
>   for Iterable, a core abstraction in Scala’s collection API. We implemented
>   “type constructor polymorphism” in Scala 2.5, which solves this problem
>   at the root, thus greatly reducing the duplication of type signatures and code.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't completely agree with you. Scala **supports** covariant aggregates. Actually, the list type is declared as class `List[+A]`. The parameter type `+A` stands as an indicator of *covariance*. Probably the problem is that the `RDD` type, which has to be used also from Java code (which does not support covariance and contravariance), is defined as *invariant* with respect to its type variable.

Comment: Seen it. But I don't understand where do you want to arrive. I mean: can you contextualize the answer to the case reported in the question?

Comment: Not claiming to be an expert at this, but from how I understand it, expressed in non technical terms, when the `Iterable` (which is in some form immutable probably) is build in the `cogroup` you need to provide a constructor for the value elements in your `Tuple2` and this constructor can not be inferred  when you use in your case `Measure[_]` . Someone with a better background in Scala and compilers may explain it better.

Comment: Nice shot! Try to modify you response in this way, and I will accept it.